# Error: No named parameter with the name 'autovalidate'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

How can fix this issue of the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cclNX.png)

```
lib/Screens/LoginPage.dart:140:29: Error: No named parameter with the name 'autovalidate'.
                            autovalidate: _autoValidate,
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/form.dart:40:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const Form({
        ^^^^
lib/Screens/ForgetPasseord.dart:110:29: Error: No named parameter with the name 'autovalidate'.
                            autovalidate: _autovalidate,
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/form.dart:40:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const Form({
```

Error: No named parameter with the name 'autovalidate'.

Answer (score 1):

`autovalidate` has been removed and replaced by `autovalidateMode` which takes a static value from `AutovalidateMode` class

ex.

```
Form(
  key: _formKey,
  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
  child: Card(
```